# let css ignore Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, browser

I have a weird problem whit my css and I cannot find a solution on the net…
I have this css for my “submenu” of the navigation bar on this site: http://ahornung.tk when I look at the submenu in every browser except Safari it needs a `margin-top: -43px;` for it to look ok but in Safari it does not…
Does a css detect web browser and ignore css if Safari rule exist?

```
.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -43px;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
}
```

**Update:**
In Safari it looks good whit out  `margin-top: -43px;`...

Comment: We'd love to look at yoor Code & CSS but you seem to have disabled right-clicking.

Comment: Try `top:10px` instead of `margin-top: -43px`.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ctrl+Alt+U.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have enabled the right click again

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell exactly what is going on but rather than using `margin-top` try using `top:0` and adjust as required.

Comment: that is the main problem
if I use top:0; the object really is on top of the page...